# Language requirements for postgraduate studies in UK and Canada?

Tags: phd, masters, united-kingdom, language-exams, canada

Universities are autonomous institutions with independent requirements and decision making procedures, on the other hand there must be some widely recognized standards.

What is the most recognized English language certificate for postgraduate (physics) studies in UK and Canada universities?

P.S. EU citizen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IELTS is widely accepted in the UK, and it is also accepted by the UK immigration authorities.

ToEFL is also widely accepted by universities but is no longer accepted by UK immigration authorities.

Comment: Should  the immigration authorities language requirements be considered when applying for academic position?

Comment: @simplicisveritatis Yes, because if you require a visa to study in the UK then it saves time and money to do a single test which can be used for both the university and the visa application.